# Enabling CORS in ASP.NET Core API for React Native app

Tags: asp.net, react-native, asp.net-core

I have an `ASP.NET Core 3.1` API backend which is already configured to allow `CORS` for my web app -- see below.

I'm now building a mobile app in `React Native`. How do I add the specific origin for my `React Native` app so that my API accepts requests from my mobile app?

I don't want to allow everyone and any app. I do want to keep it as secure as possible and specify my web and mobile apps.

Here's what's currently in my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddCors(action =>
       action.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
          builder
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .WithOrigins("https://mywebapp.com", "http://localhost:50920", "https://myaccount.service.signalr.net", "http://localhost:3000")
          .AllowCredentials()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS only applies to AJAX requests from browsers.
By adding and using CORS in your application all it does is just adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` header to the response. 
Then the browser can lookup the value of that header and either block the AJAX or allow.

So in terms of other clients than web browsers CORS has nothing to do for accessing your API

Comment: So don't we need to add cors code into our Startup.cs, if we just have react native mobile app as frontend?

Comment: no, if it is a native  mobile app, there is no such nee